# How to enable mod_rewrite in MS4W 3 Beta

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

Like the titled said, how to enable mod_rewrite modules in apache that comes with MS4W 3 Beta, i have uncomment the modules in httpd.conf, seems still not working, i have changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" (some googling result) and still not succeed, did the server build without mod_rewrite support or i'm missing something? i'm planning to use a free CMS (SilverStripe) as the main webpages and it needs mod_rewrite to enabled.

Answer (score 2):

To verify if the mod_rewrite module is present in your version, you can use this command (in a commandline window) :

apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES

Answer (score 0):

The changes you made are enough to enable mode_rewrite.
It seems you have not resarted apache properly.

Run command prompt as administrator.

From command prompt run /ms4w/apache-restart.bat

I hope, this wil fix the issue.